# How to load google spreadsheet data into SQL Server table using SSIS?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, ssis-2012

I have a Google spreadsheet with multiple tabs but i would like only one tab to get loaded into a SQL Server table using SSIS.

Is it possible to do, and if yes, how do I do?

If you can provide with example that would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance for your help

Thank you,
Swathi L

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. When you make your data flow tasks set your source as the excel sheet.

Comment: My requirement is i need to load the excel sheet from google spreadsheet. I can't use excel source in dataflow task to load the data because it is google spreadsheet.

Comment: The only thing you can really do is export the google sheet as a .csv and then set the source from there.

Comment: Do you know how to download the file from SSIS? I am not sure how to do. Your response is appreciated.

Comment: I tried this link https://zappysys.com/blog/download-file-url-using-ssis/
and its is extracting the file but when i open the file i get error message file is corrupted and in the file i see this message. I don't know what that meant
You are being redirected
<noscript>Javascript is required. Please enable javascript before you are allowed to see this page.</noscript>

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea here being, yes you can. And it isn't particularly difficult if you're familiar with creating SSIS packages, you would just use an external data flow task for the Spread Sheet reference.

That being said, the Step by Step proceedure is quite lengthy to share here, but there are some pretty good resources for that out there, such as [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/846480/Import-Data-from-Excel-to-SQL-Using-SSIS-Dynamic-C) for a physical copy, or [this link](http://www.statslice.com/leveraging-google-docs-with-ssis) for a shared Google Sheet. Note, that for shared sheets security is (IMHO) a pretty big issue to worry about.

Additionally, you may need to debug the proceess, which you could use this [Microsoft Resource.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-from-excel-with-ssis?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I tried the link that you shared Google sheet and it gave me error:
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: Script Component failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0x80131500.
Do you know what this means?